# ¿Cómo encriptar una variable php en un link?

Tags: php, variables

Tengo este código:

```
<?php
//...
// me busca el nombre de una varible que viene por el metodo get y me da un id que es una url del archivo de streaming
$canal = array_search($nombre, $array);
//...
```

Reproductor de video

```
<script src="http://btcmax.me/chanel/repro/build/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://btcmax.me/chanel/repro/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://btcmax.me/chanel/repro/build/mediaelementplayer.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://btcmax.me/chanel/repro/build/mejs-skins.css"/>

<video autoplay="true" width="700" height="450" id="player1">
    <!-- Pseudo HTML5 -->
    <source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="<?php echo $canal; ?>"/>
</video>

<script>
    $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
        success: function (player, node) {
            $('#' + node.id + '-mode').php('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Este código funciona bien, lo que quiero es que al dar <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> a la página web no muestre el valor de la variable, para que no me tomen la *url* y lo usen en otras web sin mi permiso.

Espero haberme explicado bien, no soy programador solo estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta por Internet.

Comment: Hola, no puedes evitar que se vea ellos fuentes de la página. Que es lo que quieres proteger? Si explicas cuál es el temor que tienes quizá hay otra solución. Saludos

Comment: hola amigo gracia por responder, lo que quiero es que salga encriptado la url de la varible para evitar robo de la ulr

Comment: No existe una forma de hacer lo que quieres, a fin de cuentas, el navegador necesita saber de dónde obtener ciertos recursos. Por otro lado, aunque lograras ofuscar la URL (el esfuerzo para lograrlo es fuerte), aún se podría leer en texto claro en los headers del request/response. 

Tal vez podrías valerte de otros métodos para asegurar tus recursos, podrías usar algún método de autenticación por ejemplo.

Comment: Marlon me explicas el como, pero quiero saber tu objetivo. Como ya te dijimos de esa forma no puedes proteger la información. Explica tu caso y veremos qué se puede hacer saludos.

Comment: la idea era que nos usuarios que quiera saber la url del video no la puedan ver, ya que los videos lo tengo en un servidor

Comment: la solución temporal que encontré fue es esta; $url_actual = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

$url = "midominio";
if ($url_actual == $url) {
$canal = $canal;
} else {
$canal = "0";
}
 , de esta forma poner 0 a la url

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es:

1. Crear una función que encripte el código de la variable y ese código sea el que se muestre en el enlace.
2. Cuando el usuario entre a ese enlace sera redirigido, supongamos a `http:://tupagina/link.php?adfake234dfae2`.
3. Cuando el usuario accese supongamos a esta URL `link.php?` este archivo `link.php` recibirá lo que está encriptado que es `adfake234dfae2`, lo deberá transformar en una URL válida. Algo como `http://tupagina/video1.html` y redirigirá.

Es la única forma que se me ocurre, si no quieres utilizar PHP porque solo quieres cargar el contenido en una sola página, tu código de encriptación y desencriptación tendrás que hacerlo con JavaScript, pero el contenido final sí se verá.